# uploading data into ibm connection with oAuth

Tags: ibm-sbt

We want Socialite (web-application name) user data to upload on IBM-Connections per user active stream.
It requires proper OAuth mechanism. To achieve this, we are working on OAuth to get OAuth Token and OAuth Secrete per IBM Connections user wise.

We created the AppID, Appkey and AppSecrete with the help of commands mention in IBM documents.  http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/lcwiki.nsf/xpDocViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM+Connections+4.0+documentation#action=openDocument&res_title=Registering_an_OAuth_client_with_a_provider_ic40&content=pdcontent

Now we need requestTokenURL, authorizationURL, accessTokenURL to get the access token and access secret per IBM Connection user wise.

Please advise me.

Answer (score 1):

The authorization URL should be
https://:/oauth2/endpoint/connectionsProvider/authorize

The access token URL should be
https://:/oauth2/endpoint/connectionsProvider/token

Answer (score 0):

oAuth2.0 does't have the requestToken anymore. There are only to token uri's

for our test connections environment the endpoint are
https://connections4.e-office.com/oauth2/endpoint/connectionsProvider/authorize
https://connections4.e-office.com/oauth2/endpoint/connectionsProvider/token

More details you can find here, it's about smartcloud but you can find some good information
http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/appdevwiki.nsf/xpViewTags.xsp?categoryFilter=OAuth%202.0

Comment: https://connections4.e-office.com/oauth2/endpoint/connectionsProvider/authorize ,https://connections4.e-office.com/oauth2/endpoint/connectionsProvider/token both url is not opening. Is there any configuration changes requried ?

Comment: i executed folliwng commond: ./wsadmin.sh -lang jython -conntype SOAP -c "print AdminTask.createOAuthProvider('[-providerName connectionsProvider -fileName /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer1/profiles/AppSrv01/bin/connectionsProvider.xml]')" -user wasadmin -password PASS to enable oAuthprovider...but getting follwing error : File "C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\scriptLibraries\perfTuning\V70\applyPerfTuningTemplate.py", line 362, in ?
  File "C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\scriptLibraries\perfTuning\V70\applyPerfTuningTemplate.py", line 167, in processCmdline
NameEr

Comment: you need to replace connections4.e-office.com to your domainname of your connections environment